# Access 2016 Run time error invalid use of null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am checking to see if a record exists in a Access 2016 form if it exist show a message if not add it to the database. But I am getting a invalid use of null when txtRepGrpNumber is empty, if not empty it adds it even though it already exists in the database. RepGrpNumber is a numeric field in the database. It errors out on my if statment.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSql As String
Dim message As String
Set db = CurrentDb
If Nz(CStr(Me.txtRepGrpNumber)) >= "" Then
strSql = "INSERT INTO dbo_TblSwShowRoom(RepGrpNumber, ViewOrder, RepCompany, AddressFull, Contact, Phone, Hours, ViewPhotos, ViewTour, ImageShow, Image, AddBy, DateAdded, DateChanged, ChangedBy, Enabled) " & _
         "VALUES('" & Me.txtRepGrpNumber & "','" & Me.txtViewOrder & "', '" & Me.txtRepCompany & "', '" & Me.txtAddressFull & "', '" & Me.txtContact & "', '" & Me.txtPhone & "', '" & Me.txtHours & "', '" & Me.txtViewPhotos & "', '" & Me.txtViewTour & "', '" & Me.txtImageShow & "', '" & Me.txtImage & "', '" & Me.txtAddBy & "', '" & Me.txtDateAdded & "', '" & Me.txtDateChanged & "', '" & txtChangedBy & "', '" & txtEnabled & "')"
    db.Execute strSql
    Me.SubFrmSwShowRoom.Requery
Else
    message = MsgBox("Cannot save because Group Number is Blank", vbCritical)
End If
'End If
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the run-time error? You need to set a breakpoint and capture the contents of the string with the SQL in it. Then open the query designer and try to run the query. You should be able to see the problem.

Comment: It errors out on this line If Nz(CStr(Me.txtRepGrpNumber)) >= "" Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If CStr(Nz(Me.txtRepGrpNumber,"")) <> "" Then`

Comment: I still get an error if the txtbox is empty and if the record exist it still adds it to the database

Comment: Ok, I revised it a little. Try that.

Comment: That works thanks, now I have to figure out why it still adds the record if it exists!

Comment: Note that the `CStr` explicit string conversion is redundant.

Comment: I am trying to clear my textboxes and in the database there datatype is numeric I am using this : Me.txtRepGrpNumber = "" but I get an error of you tried to assign the null value to a variable that is not a variant data type. I am not sure how to clear this with correct code.

Comment: I figured it out Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`CStr` can't convert a `Null` value. `CStr(Null)` throws the same error you're getting. This should do:

```
If Nz(Me.txtRepGrpNumber, vbNullString) <> vbNullString Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting invalid use of null is if the value of txtRepGrpNumber has not been changed since you opened the form, and it was null, CStr throws the error invalid use of null when it gets to that.

To fix it:

```
If Me.txtRepGrpNumber & vbNullString <> vbNullString Then
```